Makevars:1: *** missing separator. Stop. -> Compiling for an R package that is written in C++
Im trying to install an R packages of the following GitHub Repo:
https://github.com/MACKattenberg/cffe/tree/main
When I execute the build_package file, I get the following Error
> roxygen2::roxygenise(package.name)
ℹ Loading grf
ℹ Re-compiling grf (debug build)
── R CMD INSTALL ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─  installing *source* package ‘grf’ ... (465ms)
   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   Makevars:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
   Makevars:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘grf’
─  removing ‘/private/var/folders/27/vybh1n8109xgt1cklz66dkjr0000gn/T/RtmpXY4QFC/devtools_install_446fb3e226f/grf’
Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …`:
! System command 'R' failed
---
Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr: <printed>
---

Checking the Makevars files in  the SRC shows:
../bindings/Makevars
and the Makevars file in the Bindings Directory shows:
## Use c++11
CXX_STD = CXX11

PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I. -Isrc -DR_BUILD

SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp */*.cpp */*/*.cpp */*/*/*.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

I have tried to indent the code as mentioned in previously makefile:4: *** missing separator. Stop,
however it still does not work.
Any help would be much appreciated.




The "missing separators" error is typical of makefiles where indentation doesn't begin with an actual tab. It doesn't look like the actual error is in the Makevars file, but you should still look at it with a hex-editor to make sure there's no invisible characters on the first line. If there isn't, then the error is somewhere else, and you need to go back to the repository owners and ask them about them. Possibly add an error report for the repository on Github.

could you elaborate what you mean by 'there's no invisible characters on the first line.' - I can use VS code as a hex-editor ?
also, should I indent any of the code:
Use c++11
CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I. -Isrc -DR_BUILD
SOURCES = $(wildcard .cpp /.cpp //.cpp ///.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

You should not indent anything in Makevars, it's fine as it is. And you can probably ask VS Code to display a file as hex. The file should start with two 23 values (in hex) which is the ASCII encoding of the character #. If there's another value at the start, then it might be the problem. If there isn't another character at the start, you really need to contact the maintainers of the repository, because it's not really something many here could help you with.

I have posted a screenshot of the file as hex. It does start with 23, so I guess there seems to be wrong with the Github Repo? Thanks for your help, I will contact the Authors

Although the diagnostic message looks like one of make's, there does not appear to be any makefile in the package repository (the Makevars files don't seem quite to be that), and make does not appear to be invoked explicitly by anything there.  I have therefore removed the [makefile] tag.
